# Where do den den mushi come from?

Tags: one-piece

Is it ever explained where the den den mushi come from?

We know there are all kind of den den mushi variating in colors as well in functions. But do they originate from a devil fruit user or are they just some random existing creature in the One piece universe ?
[image]

Comment: They are just your average little critter snail that got a reciever attached to them in order to be used as cellphones :P

Comment: @Robin what you call your average little snail, I don't see our snails running around with radio wave communication.

Comment: they just a usual snail that have the ability to communicate with each other using some kind of telepathy. Human add some kind of device that help them to transfer and receive signal from each other

Comment: @ShinobuOshino oy oy that exact fact they can use that does make them not normal :|

Comment: @Dimitrimx I mean it has nothing to do with devil fruit or anything. It's just 'regular' animal in One Piece world.

Comment: @Dimitrimx I don't remember if it ever explained in manga or anime but I think it mentioned on [SBS](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Den den mushi are kind of snails used for visual and audio communication. They are just another type of random creature existing in OPverse which uses telepathic abilities for communication within their own kind.

[Source](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Den_Den_Mushi)